VS stops working after 1-2 seconds after login without any errors
VS 2022 stops working after 1-2 seconds after login without any errors. At first I tried to restart the PC - did not help; then I tried to reinstall Visual Studio 2022 - crashes when you start to reinstall the application and started to occur an error

The microsoft.visualstudio.shell.connected.userinformation.userinformationpackage package did not load correctly enter image description here

Of the latest changes in the system: changed the user’s directory (renamed from Cyrillic to Latin, because some applications did not work). Maybe after that there was a problem, not sure

I suggest that you report this problem to the Visual Studio Team. Open Visual Studio Installer, on the top right click on Provide Feedback -> Report a Problem.

Found the solution! I have been helped by deleting this folder in the following way:
%appdata%\Local.IdentityService
